# cannot convert from 'string' to 'object'

Tags: c#, queue, contains

I'm doing homework and I can't do this part where I need to see if a name is contained in the queue:

```
public struct person
{
    public string name;
    public string bday;
    public int age;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        person personaStruct = new person();
        Queue<person> personQueue = new Queue<person>();

        Console.WriteLine("Type a name");
        personStruct.name = Console.ReadLine();

        if (personQueue.Contains(personStruct.name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(personStruct.name);
            Console.WriteLine(personStruct.bday);
            Console.WriteLine(personStruct.age);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doesn't exist!");
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to show me the complete queue(name, bday, age)

Comment: i'm getting the error in : if(personQueue.contains(personStruct)) ----
personQueue is the queue

Comment: `personQueue` is also the problem. Until you [show us code that compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) we can't help you.

Comment: i'm not really good in english but can i like send you a print of the code or something? i cant really explain , if not its ok ill just try to explain,,, public struct person
{
    public string name;
    public string bday;
    public int age;
}
person personStruct = new person();
            Queue<person> personQueue = new Queue<person>();

Comment: The error makes it *sound like* you think it - whatever it is - contains objects, but it really contains strings

Comment: Post code that compiles into your question. And `person` should be a class not a struct.

Comment: @Young King you can edit your question to include more of the code, in particular the declaration/definitions of the structs like personQueue would help us help you.

Comment: the problem is that i need to use struct (teacher's order...")

Comment: if `personQueue` is a `Queue<person>` and `personStruct` is an instance of `person`, then the given code does not reproduce the error you're getting. Please edit your question with a complete code sample that reproduces the error you're getting.

Comment: Hmm, a queue isn't really good datatype for this, I believe. But however it's homework, let's have a guess what it should teach you. `Contains()` only returns true if the exact element is in the queue. But you should search for the name only, regardless of the birthday and age (which is redundant BTW). So you're probably supposed to `Dequeue()` all items and check if the name of of an item matches. Of course you need to `Enque()` a dequeued item back. To know when you're done, you can use `Count()`. (Or you could cheat, use `ToArray()` and `Array.Exists()`.)

Comment: @JSteward ive edidted it see if you could help me now

Comment: The only error you get from the currently posted code is _`personStruct` does not exist in the current context_ because this line: `person personaStruct = new person();` has a typo, it should be `personStruct` not `personaStruct`. But still it does not reproduce the error you're claiming.

Comment: @JSteward Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'person' Trabalho 1 E:\PSI\Módulo 6\Trabalho 1\Trabalho 1\Program.cs 44 Active

Comment: @stickybit im trying it now

Comment: Required reading for teacher: **[Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)**

Comment: @YoungKing Now you've added `if (personQueue.Contains(personStruct.name))` note the `.name`, that's your error

Comment: @JSteward but if i dont add the .name how do i search to see if it contains? thats my problem

Comment: `personQueue = new Queue<person>()` means `personQueue` contains `person` not names. Are you searching for a person or for a name because those are two very different things.

Comment: @DourHighArch im searching for a name that if it exists it will show me the name, bday and age of a person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a matching person by name filter your queue by name, then look for any remaining matches. Take the first match and print that to the user assuming there can only be one match in your queue. If `person` was a class instead of struct you could also just use `FirstOrDefault` and check for null but with a struct this might be the simplest way.

```
var matchingPeopele = personQueue.Where(p => p.name == personStruct.name);
if (matchingPeopele.Any())
{
    var match = matchingPeopele.First();
    Console.WriteLine(match.name);
    Console.WriteLine(match.bday);
    Console.WriteLine(match.age);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doesn't exist!");
}
```

With respect to your comment, that your teacher hasn't covered LINQ yet, here's another version. At this point I'm basically doing your homework for you but please try your best to really understand what's going on as you try out the code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    person personStruct = new person();
    Queue<person> personQueue = new Queue<person>();

    Console.WriteLine("Type a name");
    personStruct.name = Console.ReadLine();

    var personFound = false;
    foreach(var p in personQueue)
    {
        if (p.name == personStruct.name)
        {
            personFound = true;
            Console.WriteLine(p.name);
            Console.WriteLine(p.bday);
            Console.WriteLine(p.age);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!personFound)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doesn't exist!");
    }
}
```

Comment: it did work the only problem is that my teacher hasnt taught us how to use none of that code like none of this : ```code``` var matchingPeopele = personQueue.Where(p => p.name == personStruct.name);
if (matchingPeopele.Any())
{
    var match = matchingPeopele.First(); 

---- but thanks man ill just use it and hope the teacher doesnt complain thank you very much :D

Comment: @YoungKing I simplified  the code a bit, hopefully it's a bit easier to understand

Comment: thats it thank you so much man i did understand the code i actually never thought this site would be useful but it is thanks!